# SQL server-2008

Tags: sql, windows-server-2008

Plz help me to solve this what is the query

```
ID  Name    Items
101 A   x
102 B   Y
101 A   Z
102 B   S
102 B   J
101 A   Q
```

Now i have to show

```
Id      Name    Items
101         A   X
                Z
                Q
102         B   Y
                S
                J
```

Comment: Do this in your presentation layer.

Comment: Please use real words and give this a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of SQL which generates temporary table like one in your question and then outputs data using CTE (common table expression) and `case` statements. tested in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    id INT,
    Name varchar,
    items varchar
);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
(101, 'A',  'x'),
(102, 'B',  'Y'),
(101, 'A',  'Z'),
(102, 'B',  'S'),
(102, 'B',  'J'),
(101, 'A',  'Q');

WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT CAST(id AS varchar) AS id
        , name
        , items
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM #test
)
SELECT
     (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN id   ELSE '' END) AS id
    ,(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN name ELSE '' END) AS name
    ,items
FROM tmp;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't quite do that in a sql query. if it's just the ordering you want, then this:

```
 select id, name, items 
 from tableName
 order by id, name, items desc
```

but that's not what you want, is it?